# RadCombobox property losing value between GotFocus and LostFocus

Tags: wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I have a radcombobox whose property loses it value somewhere between the GotFocus and LostFocus event.

XAML:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboWoodSpecies" 
    FontSize="16"  Margin="0,4,0,0" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text="{Binding woodSpecies, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="WoodSpecies" 
    IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0"
    Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >
```

GotFocus event:

```
Private Sub cboWoodSpecies_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles cboWoodSpecies.GotFocus

    BindComboBoxes.WoodSpecies(cboWoodSpecies)  'bind cbo to data


    If thisOrder.woodSpecies <> String.Empty Then   'Property OK here!!
        DisplayWoodSpeciesImage()
    End If
End Sub
```

DisplayWoodSpeciesImage reads the value of the property but does not reset it to Nothing.

LostFocus:

```
Private Sub cboWoodSpecies_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles cboWoodSpecies.LostFocus

    If thisOrder.woodSpecies <> String.Empty Then   'Property = Nothing.  Why?!?!
        'do stuff
    End If

End Sub
```

I think it has something to do with the combobox itself.  Selecting a new item from the combo does not cause the problem.  It's filling the combo with existing data that causes the problem.  I have to reselect the item to bypass the error.

That being said, is there a way to refresh the combobox so it thinks the item has been selected again?  Is it something with SelectedItem that needs to be set?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: What exactly does the BindComboBoxes.WoodSpecies method do? How it is implemented?

Comment: like so: 'Public Class BindComboBoxes

    Public Shared Sub WoodSpecies(thisCombo As RadComboBox)

 'stuff
 
            da.Fill(dt)
            thisCombo.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView

            thisCombo.IsTextSearchEnabled = True
            thisCombo.StaysOpenOnEdit = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            'stuff

        Finally
            

        End Try

    End Sub

Comment: And what kind of property is "woodSpecies"?

Comment: Private _woodSpecies As String
    Public Property woodSpecies As String
        Get
            Return _woodSpecies
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _woodSpecies = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("woodSpecies")
        End Set
End Property

Comment: Does the DataTable has a column named "woodSpecies"?

Comment: It's aliased:              s = _
                "SELECT WoodType AS WoodSpecies, COALESCE(WoodTypeImageName, '') AS WoodTypeImageName, ' {' + CAST(PctUpchrgB * 100 AS nvarchar) + '%}' AS pctUpcharge " & _
                "FROM " & theTable & " " & _
                "ORDER BY " & theTable & ".WoodType"

Comment: What if you set the SelectedValuePath of the ComboBox to "WoodSpecies" and bind the SelectedValue (instead of the Text property) to "woodSpecies"?

Comment: Changed xaml to this but still lose the property in LostFocus:  
                                             ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                             SelectedValue="{Binding woodSpecies, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                             SelectedValuePath="woodSpecies"
                                             telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="WoodSpecies" 
                                             IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0"
                                             Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >

Comment: SelectedValuePath should be "WoodSpecies with a capital W. Could you please provide a repo of your issue?: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK, that seemed to fix the problem.  Let me test this and I'll post again if I have an issue.  Thanks.  I don't see a way to mark your response as an answer.

Comment: I posted this as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `SelectedValuePath` of the `ComboBox` to "WoodSpecies" and bind the `SelectedValue` (instead of the `Text` property) to "woodSpecies":

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboWoodSpecies" 
FontSize="16"  Margin="0,4,0,0" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" 
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
SelectedValuePath="WoodSpecies"
SelectedValue="{Binding woodSpecies, Mode=TwoWay}" 
telerik:TextSearch.TextPath="WoodSpecies" 
IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" TabIndex="0"
Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >
```